# Using a String array in a thread function

Tags: c, pthreads, signals

I'm trying to pass an array to thread function so that it has access to the array in the function. For the moment it just contains the name of the threads.

```
const char *a[2];
char *s = "Thread 1";
char *r = "Thread 2";
a[0] = s;
a[1] = r;
pthread_create(&t, NULL, oddhandler, (void *)a[0]);
pthread_create(&y, NULL, evenhandler, (void *)a[1]);
```

The intention is to write the create like this

```
pthread_create(&t, NULL, oddhandler, &a);
pthread_create(&y, NULL, evenhandler, &a);
```

How would I re-write this function to accommodate this change?

```
static void *
oddhandler(void *p)
{
    char *q = (char *)p;
    printf("%s is ready.\n", q);
    sigset_t set;
    int sig = SIGUSR1;

    sigemptyset(&set);

    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);

    while (1) {

       /* Wait for SIGUSR1 */
       sigwait(&set, &sig);

       printf("%s received a SIGUSR1!\n", q);

    }

    return ((void *)NULL);
}
```

Comment: Is it your intention that each thread proc will receive the base address of `a`, the array of char pointers?

Comment: So you want the created threads to know automatically which index to use to get their name? i.e. rather than passing the name in, you pass just the beginning of the array a and each thread knows by what amount to index a for itself?

Comment: No, the idea is that a[0] and a[1] will replace q in the print statement. I'm just using the thread names as an example. The threads will both be printing strings that have been placed in that array.

Comment: Since you're all in one address space can't you just reference 'a' anyway? Or are you trying to avoid it becoming that widely seen?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I didn't try making the array a global variable because I was too focused on making it an argument. I wasn't thinking out side the box enough.

Comment: Well depending on what you're doing with it, don't forget to lock it if you have multiple threads going at it...

Comment: Why not just make a `static const char * thread_title = "Thread 1";` in `oddhandler`, and a similar variable in `evenhandler`? That won't scale very well if you have hundreds of different thread routines, but for two, it's a pretty reasonable approach...

Answer (score 0):

You could try coupling the thread id with the thread data :

```
typedef struct thread_info {
  int thread_id; // different for every thread
  void * thread_data; // the same for every thread
}
```

As in your example program, you could create one function, handler, and have threads adjust based on their id.

```
pthread_create(&(t[id], NULL, handler, &(info[i]));

void * handler(void * info) {
   thread_info * myInfo = (thread_info *) info;
   char *q = ((char *) myInfo->thread_data) + myInfo->thread_id;

   // rest of function
}
```